# Change Split view programmatically based on orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I realize apples documentation suggests a split view should be set as the root view controller. So essentially I have an app with a tab bar. Inside of the first index of the tab bar I have a split view. When the device's orientation is in portrait, I want the (master detail of the split) to fill the whole screen or become the detail page, but more importantly not have the option to have a master detail when the device is in portrait. So my thought is that I swap out tab bar indexes based on the devices orientation. Here's what my code looks like:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
        if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) )
    {

       UISplitViewController * splitview = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
//        
//        splitview.delegate =self;
//        [splitview willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];






        NSLog(@"LandScape!!");

        NSMutableArray * array = [MyCustomwViewManager changeHomeOrientationTolandScape:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers] viewController:self navigationController:self.navigationController splitView:splitview];

     [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:array animated:YES];

        // [self viewDidLoad];

    } else {

        NSMutableArray * changeSplit = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.splitViewController.viewControllers];


        NSMutableArray * array = [MyCustomViewManager changeHomeOrientationToPortrait:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers] viewController:[changeSplit objectAtIndex:0] navigation:[changeSplit objectAtIndex:0]];


           [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:array animated:YES];


    }



}
```

My goal is to achieve something similar to the yelp iPad app. Hopefully I am clear and make sense.